# Finding parent objects in nested arrays of objects. How?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion, data-structures

I have a data structure that looks like this:

```
var someDataStructure = [
  {
    opts: {_id:1}
  },
  {
    opts: {_id: 2},
    children: [
      {
        opts: {_id: 3},
        children: [
          {
            opts: {_id: 4}
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    opts: {_id: 5}
  },
  {
    opts: {_id: 6},
    children: [
      {
        opts: {_id: 7},
        children: [
          {
            opts: {_id: 8}
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }  
];
```

That's an array of objects, all with an `opts` property, and an optional `children` property.  If it exists the `children` property will be an array of the same sort of objects.

Given any `opts._id`, I need to find the `_id` of all parent objects. The `_id`'s I give here are only sequential for convenience.  *You may not assume they are sequential integers*

This project is using both jquery and lodash so both of those libraries are available for use.

Example desired output:

- Given `4`, return `[2, 3]`.
- Given `3`, return `[2]`.
- Given `8`, return `[6, 7]`.
- Given `7`, return `[6]`.

I have no problem recursing in and finding the given `_id`.  However, I'm feeling dumb and stuck on maintaining the array of parents.

Comment: each opts can have only one children?

Comment: Are you sure those examples of desired output are correct?

Comment: Gives 8 return [6,7]; gives 2 return []

Comment: @Linus sorry, fixed desired output.  That's what I get for doing too much editing and not enough proofreading.

Comment: @AlessandroMarchisio children can be nested to any depth.

Comment: @AlessandroMarchisio oh, I think you meant can the children array have more than one object.  The answer is yes.  The children array can be any length but, taking the array with _id: 8, every child in that array would have an answer of [6, 7].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution returning found status and parents if found.

```
function getParentsHelper(tree, id, parents) {
    if (tree.opts._id == id) {
        return {
            found: true,
            parents: parents
        };
    }
    var result = {
        found: false,
    }
    if (tree.children) {
        $.each(tree.children, function(index, subtree) {
            var maybeParents = $.merge([], parents);
            if (tree.opts._id != undefined) {
                maybeParents.push(tree.opts._id);
            }
            var maybeResult = getParentsHelper(subtree, id, maybeParents);
            if (maybeResult.found) {
                result = maybeResult;
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
    return result;
}

function getParents(data, id) {
    var tree = {
        opts: { },
        children: data
    }
    return getParentsHelper(tree, id, []);
}
```

Usage example:

```
console.log(getParents(someDataStructure, 4).parents);
console.log(getParents(someDataStructure, 3).parents);
console.log(getParents(someDataStructure, 8).parents);
console.log(getParents(someDataStructure, 7).parents);
```

Answer (score 0):

for one children this works:

```
function writeParent(id, arr) {

    var ct = 0;
    var found = false;
    var parentsLine = []; 

    arr.some(function (e){
        parentsLine = []

        for (var curr = e; curr.children != null; curr = curr.children[0]) {
            if (id == curr.opts._id) {
                found = true;
                return true;
            } 
            parentsLine.push(curr.opts._id)    

        }  

        if (id == curr.opts._id) {
            found = true;
            return true;
        } 


    })
    if (found) {
        return parentsLine;
    } else {
        return "ERR: elm not found";
    }    
}
```

see http://jsfiddle.net/alemarch/ufrLpLfx/11/